# Is there an API to access Autodesk Drive?

Tags: api, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I'm trying to manage files from Autodesk Drive, I know there is a Forge API to access some Autodesk Apps but I haven't been able to find enough information to use it for Autodesk Drive (https://drive.autodesk.com/).

Doing a GET request to query hubs shows Autodesk360 hubs but nothing for Autodesk Drive.

Answer (score 0):

No, for the moment there is no public API for Autodesk Drive.
If you want to have the same functionality as with (now discontinued) A360, you will have to rely on Fusion360 hub - this is what now you get redirected to, if you try to login to https://a360.autodesk.com/.
Fusion360 hub is supported by Data Management API and it can be used without Fusion360 app itself.